# Consistency of the collection axiom scheme compared to replacement

Tags: set-theory

Set theory ZFC- is ZFC without power set, but with replacement.  It does not imply the collection axiom scheme, as discussed in http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/

Does consistency of ZFC- imply consistency of that plus collection?   I do not mind taking all of ZFC- as metatheory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, because you can go to $L$.

More specifically, if $M$ is a model of ZFC-, defined with
replacement, then consider $L^M$, the class of sets that $M$
thinks arise in the constructible hierarchy. It is not difficult
to see that $M$ thinks $L_\alpha$ exists for every ordinal
$\alpha$ that it has, and ultimately one can see that $L^M$ is a
model of ZFC-, since instances of replacement inside $L^M$ amount
to instances of replacement in $M$, since $L^M$ is definable in
$M$. But now, since $L^M$ has a definable well-ordering of the
universe, it has a definable Skolem function and this means that
$L^M$ models $\text{ZFC}^-$, defined with collection+separation.

So the consistency of ZFC-, defined with replacement, implies the
consistency of $\text{ZFC}^-$, defined with collection+separation.

That said, the main point of our article is that ZFC-, defined
with replacement, is the wrong version of this theory, since so
many things go wrong in it.

Comment: It follows from this argument that the class of hereditarily countable sets of a ZFC- model, defined with replacement, will not necessarily satisfy ZFC-, because in the examples of some of our models in the paper, the $L$ of that collection will be $L_{\aleph_\omega^L}$, which does not satisfy replacement.